# Manage tap event on an component over another component

Tags: sencha-touch-2, listener

I have a panel with a tap listener (red square) and, over it, a button (green). Something like this:

[image]

When the button is pressed I want to avoid the tap listener of the red square, but I cant find the way to do this. Could you help me?

This example is not exactly my code (im using controller, dataitems, etc) but is the same problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6ah6U/

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'panel',
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    style: 'background: #ff0000',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        style: 'background: #00ff00',
        listeners: {
            tap: function() {
                console.log('green tapped');
            },
            element: 'element'
        },
    }],
    listeners: {
        tap: function() {
            console.log('red tapped');
        },
        element: 'element'
    },
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: I have edited my post. Its not my real code but is the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stop the propagation of the event in the function handling the tap event on the green panel:

```
tap: function(btn, e) {
  alert('green tapped');
  e.stopPropagation();
},
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can give your green square an id:

```
.......
height: 50,
width: 50,
id: 'green'
.......
```

Then inside `listeners` of your red square which is your parent element, you can check the `target` of your `tap event` to see whether it's green square or not:

```
listeners: {
    tap: function(e, node) {
        if(node.parentNode.id !== 'green') {
            console.log('red tapped');
        }
     },
     element: 'element'
}
```

Notice that I'm using [parentNode](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317) to follow properly HTML structure of Sencha Touch in this case. You can use inspect element tool to have better understanding about it.

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6ah6U/1/

Comment: This would not work if the user taps on any children of the #green panel